# How to update a flutter progress bar in a for loop?

Tags: flutter, function, dart, for-loop, progress-bar

I have a progress bar widget in my flutter app that progress should be updated after each iteration of a `for-loop` but the values are not updating and just when the loop is finished, the last value of the loop is shown.
I think the problem is the for a loop because with a simple timer, the progress bar works but with my own function in a `for-loop`, values do not update until the loop finishes.

```
class CircularDeterministicProgressBar extends StatefulWidget {


  CircularDeterministicProgressBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CircularDeterministicProgressBar> createState() =>
      _CircularDeterministicProgressBarState();
}

class _CircularDeterministicProgressBarState
    extends State<CircularDeterministicProgressBar> {

  double progressPercent = 0.0;

  _CircularDeterministicProgressBarState();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    var stream = counter(10000);
    stream.listen(
          (data) {
            setState(() {
              progressPercent = data;
            });
        print("data is after Change: "+data.toString());
      },
      onError: (err) {
        print('Error: ${err}');
      },
      cancelOnError: false,
      onDone: () {
        print('Done!');
      },
    );

  }

  Stream<double> counter(int length) async* {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      double percent = (i / length);
      String percentText = percent.toString() + "%";
      yield percent;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CircularPercentIndicator(
          radius: 120.0,
          lineWidth: 13.0,
          animation: false,
          percent: progressPercent,
          center: new Text(
            "Percent",
            style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
          footer: new Text(
            "ProgressBar",
            style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17.0),
          ),
          circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
          progressColor: Colors.purple,
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: this is because your `counter` generator will yield all the values in fraction of millisecond - it will work if you add `await Future.delayed(someMillisecondsSmallDelay)` before calling `yield percent;`

Comment: @pskink thank you, your solution really helped me & solved my problem.

Comment: sure, your welcome